# React Hook - props value doesn't change immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Any idea how to force props.name to update its value immediately? This displays correctly on the Select box, but when I try to retrieve props.name from another file/its child, the value is **delayed by one click**.

```
 const [name, setName] = React.useState(props.name)
 useEffect(() => { setName(props.name) }, [props.name]);

...
 <Select
    labelId="tribe-label"
    id="name"
    name="name"
    key={props.name}
    defaultValue={props.name}
    onChange={e => {props.handleChange(e);
                let dataUpdated = {
                  ...props,
                  [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
                };
                setName(dataUpdated);
                console.log(props.name)}}
    label="Name"
    renderValue={(value) => value ? value : "All"}
    displayEmpty
    notched
    fullWidth
  >
   <MenuItem value="All">All</MenuItem>
   {Object.entries(searchKey).map((entry, index) => {                
       return (
               <MenuItem key={index} value={entry[1]}>
                    {entry[1]}
               </MenuItem>
               );
              })}
   </Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onChange` event handler, it seems like `props.handleChange(e)` is updating the `name` state in the parent component so it will rerender and pass `name` as props to child and since you include `props.name` in the `useEffect` dependency array of child then this will update its own `name` state, therefore you don't need

```js
let dataUpdated = {...props, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
setName(dataUpdated);
```

because if `props.name` is updated then `name` in child will be updated anyway with `useEffect` so it will do twice

note also that

```js
console.log(props.name)
```

from inside an event handler will show `props.name` of the current render before any state update you make, `console.log(props.name)` from the body of your component instead to see updated `props.name` on each render

Comment: When I only used useEffect, the value of props.name didn't change immediately. Hence I added let dataUpdated within onChange. This addition didn't resolve the issue. I also have run console.log from its child file to confirm the value.

Comment: from what I know `setName(dataUpdated)` wont trigger useEffect because it does not update `name` in the parent component, can you include the parent component code?